# signalr send comment to connected client but within specific post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, signalr

Say there are 50 post on the page. Each post contains some comments.
When I click a post a popup appears with comments.

What is happening is that if two users are connected to the server. One is seeing post 1 and the other seeing post 34,  each sending a comment, the comments got exchanged.

How can I tell signalr to send the post to each other if and only if that specific post id is opened for comments in the popup window? I am new to this. any pointer will do.

This is my working code

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.hub = $.connection.chathub;
  self.commenttext = ko.observable();
  self.comments = ko.observableArray();
  self.commentdate = ko.observable();


  self.init = function() {
    self.hub.server.getPosts().fail(function(err) {
      console.log("connection started");
    });
  }

  self.hub.client.loadPosts = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.comments);
  }

  self.hub.client.newCommentss = function(comment) {
    self.comments.push(comment);
  }

  self.addcomments = function() {
    var t = {
      "comment": self.commenttext(),
      "cardid": 20
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("
      AddComments ", "
      Home ")",
      type: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(t),
      success: function(data) {
        self.hub.server.addCommentss(t).done(function(comment) {


        }).fail(function(err) {

        });
      }
    });
  }


};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
  vm.init();
});
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <textarea data-bind="value: commenttext"></textarea><br />
  <a href="#" data-bind="click: addcomments" style="margin-bottom:4em">Send</a><br /><br /><br />
  <ul data-bind="foreach: comments,visible: comments().length > 0">
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text:commentdate"></span>
      <strong><span data-bind="text: comment"> </span></strong><br /><br />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my chathub

```
 public class chathub : Hub
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public chathub(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {          
        _context = context;
    }

    public void GetComments(int id)
    {
        List<CommentsViewModel> commentss= new List<CommentsViewModel>();
        var comments = _context.Comments.Where(m => m.cardid == id);
        foreach (var item in comments)
        {
            CommentsViewModel b = new CommentsViewModel();
            b.commentid = item.commentid;
            b.comment = item.comment;
            b.commentdate = item.commentdate;
            b.cardid = item.cardid;
            commentss.Add(b);
        }
        Clients.All.loadComments(commentss);
    }
    public bool addCommentss(Comment newComment)
    {
        Comment commentobj = new Comment();
        commentobj.comment = newComment.comment;
        commentobj.commentdate = System.DateTime.Now;
        commentobj.cardid = newComment.cardid;
        _context.Add(commentobj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        Clients.All.newCommentss(commentobj);
        return true;
    }

    public bool removeCommentss(int id)
    {
        Comment commentobject = _context.Comments.FirstOrDefault(m => m.commentid == id);
        if (commentobject != null)
        {
            _context.Comments.Remove(commentobject);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
       // return Json(true);
        Clients.All.deleteCommentss(commentobject);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How we have planned to do it by creating diff groups / channels for each post. when someone is on one post (comments popup) then he will get updates / pushes / post related to only that post

Comment: a connection will be created and the use gets added to the group when user opens a popup? and when he closes the popup he got removed?

Comment: yes. this is exactly the thing. also as i remember there is no over head to create a separate group in signalr.

Comment: @Parv Sharma  how can i remove the connection from the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a simple solution, you can do like this.

```
// save opened/clicked post ID into a local variable (clear when closed)
var currentPostID = 22;

// in your signalr receive event
self.hub.client.newCommentss = function(comment) {
  // assuming cardid is postID
  if(currentPostID == comment.cardid) {
    self.comments.push(comment);
  }
}
```

this way every online user receives new comment but only who's viewing that post will able to see it.

Or you can follow this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) for more managed way of user grouping at server side